# How can I flatten a multilevel nested list to a specified depth?

Tags: r, list, flatten

I am trying to flatten a list that has 3 levels into a list that has 2 levels.... In other words, I have a nested list as such :

```
ls <- list(
  a = list(
    a1 = list(
       a11 = list(data),
    a2 = list(
       a21 = list(data2)),
  b = list(
    b1 = list(
       b11 = list(data3),
    b2 = list(
       b21 = list(data4)))
```

I would like to flatten this so that it looks like this:

```
flat_ls <- list(
  a_a1 = list(
     a11 = list(data),
  a_a2 = list(
     a21 = list(data2)),
  b_b1 = list(
     b11 = list(data3),
  b_b2 = list(
     b21 = list(data4)))
```

I know there function `flatten()` or `lapply(rapply(y, enquote, how="unlist"), eval)` can make a multilevel list into a flat list. However, I want to keep the last layer of the list, without flattening that. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`purrr::flatten()` actually does exactly what you're looking for. per (purrr) the documentation, `flatten()` and friends "only ever remove a single layer of hierarchy."

```
library(purrr)

# placeholder values for `data` etc
data <- as.symbol("data")
data2 <- as.symbol("data2")
data3 <- as.symbol("data3")
data4 <- as.symbol("data4")

# added a few missing parens; raised error in original
ls <- list(
  a = list(
    a1 = list(
      a11 = list(data)
    ),
    a2 = list(
      a21 = list(data2)
    )
  ),
  b = list(
    b1 = list(
      b11 = list(data3)
    ),
    b2 = list(
      b21 = list(data4)
    )
  )
)

# (added step in response to comment): 
# combine top two levels of names
ls_renamed <- imap(ls, ~ set_names(.x, paste(.y, names(.x), sep = "_")))

# flatten top level
flat_ls <- flatten(ls_renamed)

dput(flat_ls)
# list(
#   a_a1 = list(
#     a11 = list(data)
#   ), 
#   a_a2 = list(
#     a21 = list(data2)
#   ), 
#   b_b1 = list(
#     b11 = list(data3)
#   ), 
#   b_b2 = list(
#     b21 = list(data4)
#   )
# )
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can merge the names of the outer list to the next layer list? The reason being is that the inner lists actually have the same names, so the real distinguishing feature is the outer list. But I would like to flatten this so 'a' with inner list 'a1' becomes 'a_a1'.

Comment: @JVDeasyas123 Sure -- I added this to my edited answer. It's easiest to do this before flattening. You can iterate over the top-level lists and their names using `purrr::imap()`, setting the names of the 2nd-level lists using `purrr::set_names(.x, paste(.y, names(.x), sep = "_"))`.